# Turn off screen on Android

Tags: android, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I am trying to turn on and off the display after a certain action happens (Lets just worry about turning the screen off for now). From what I understand from wake lock, this is what I have:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);    
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
```

When I read other posts on stackoverflow and else where, they seem to tell me that PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK will turn the screen off. But if I read the SDK it says that it will only allow the screen to be turned off. I think this isn't right.

Comment: I'm also struggling with this and I must add: CERTAINLY TEST WITHOUT YOUR CABLE CONNECTED!!! many devices display different behavior with or without cable connected so if you want to test it, install your app; disconnect your cable and only then test your app!!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two choices for turning the screen off:

```
PowerManager manager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

// Choice 1
manager.goToSleep(int amountOfTime);

// Choice 2
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = manager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Your Tag");
wl.acquire();
wl.release();
```

You will probably need this permission too:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

**UPDATE:**

Try this method; android turns off the screen once the light level is low enough.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
params.flags |= LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
params.screenBrightness = 0;
getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

Comment: In my experience these methods are highly unreliable.

Comment: Hi Arash, When i try the first choice I get a force close. I tried debugging it but that doesn't seem to work either. I just manager.goToSleep(1000); I am not sure what the 1000 means. When I try choice 2, i get nothing to happen. Are we sure that this will actually turn off the display? or will it just prevent from anything else turning off the display. I alos have the permissions set in the manifest. Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks, this does turn the screen off! However, when my timer runs and the brightness is restored, all i see is a Blank screen with the backlight on. Any Idea what thats happening? Thanks so much again!

Comment: You might be increasing the brightness too much since it is supposed to be a value between 0 and 1. I recommend you first store the value of the original screen brightness (as a float/double) and then change the value. Then, when the phone is turned on, it can be returned to its original value.

Comment: Also, setting a value of less than 0, sets the brightness to the default (preferred screen brightness).

Comment: Thanks for your responses again! I tried using -1, 0, and using the variable that saved (getWindow().getAttributes().screenBrightness; earlier) to restore it, every time it returns to just a black screen with the back light on. Do you have any other suggestions maybe?

Comment: I can't think of anything else that might work. Try looking at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_FULL) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803248/android-dim-screen-while-user-inactive) to help you out.

Comment: Well you answered most of my question! htanks

Comment: Your first method, choice one, requires DEVICE_POWER permission.

Comment: Hi A. Abiri, is screenBrightness = 0 setting will work in BroadcastReceiver onReceive method ? it's not working for me.

Comment: DEVICE_POWER permission is only allowed if you created the Android ROM image. you need to sign your apk with the root rom signature key for DEVICE_POWER permission to be granted to you app.. it ain't gonna happen.

Comment: * Force the device to go to sleep. Overrides all the wake locks that are held.     * 
     * @param time is used to order this correctly with the wake lock calls. 
     *          The time  should be in the SystemClock.uptimeMillis() time base.
     */
    public void goToSleep(long time) 
    {
        try {
            mService.goToSleep(time);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
        }
    }

usage:
mService.goToSleep(SystemClock.uptimeMillis());

Comment: The choice 2, It's not working. I can't turn off screen..

and The choice 3, It's not turn off screen, that's set brightness = 0.

Comment: Do not forget `import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;`

Answer (score 10):

The following is copied from [SDK document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html).
If you want to keep screen on, I think `SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK` is enough.

---

```
Flag Value                CPU   Screen  Keyboard
```

---

```
PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK          On*    Off      Off

SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK       On     Dim      Off

SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK    On     Bright   Off

FULL_WAKE_LOCK             On     Bright   Bright
```

---

Answer (score 5):

For me those methods didn't work. So I used other scenario (not trivial) to make my screen off.

Android has 2 flags that responsible to be awake:

- Display --> Screen TimeOut
- Application --> Development --> *Stay awake while charging* check box.

I used followed flow:

1. 1st of all save your previous configuration, for example screen timeout was 1 min and  *Stay awake while charging* checked.
2. After, I uncheck *Stay awake while charging* and set screen timeout to minimal time.
3. I register to broadcast receiver service to get event from android that screen turned off.
4. When I got event on screen off, I set previous configuration to default: screen timeout was 1 min and  *Stay awake while charging* checked.
5. Unregister receiver

After 15 sec. device sleeps

Here is snippets of code:

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

/**
 * Catch Screen On/Off
 * */
public class BroadcastReceiverScreenListener extends BroadcastReceiver{

private BroadCastListenerCallBackItf mBroadCastListenerCallBack = null;

public BroadcastReceiverScreenListener(
        BroadCastListenerCallBackItf broadCastListenerCallBack) {
    this.mBroadCastListenerCallBack = broadCastListenerCallBack;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {


    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        mBroadCastListenerCallBack.broadCastListenerCallBack__ScreenOff_onResponse();
    }       
}

}
```

**Interface used as callback**

```
public interface BroadCastListenerCallBackItf {
    public void broadCastListenerCallBack__ScreenOff_onResponse();
}
```

**2 methods from main class:**

```
....

AndroidSynchronize mSync = new AndroidSynchronize();

....

public void turnScreenOff(int wait){
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);

    BroadCastListenerCallBackItf broadCastListenerCallBack = this;

    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiverScreenListener(broadCastListenerCallBack);       
    m_context.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);



    //set Development --> disable STAY_ON_WHILE_PLUGGED_IN
    Settings.System.putInt(
            m_context.getContentResolver(), 
            Settings.System.STAY_ON_WHILE_PLUGGED_IN,
            0                                );



    // take current screen off time 
    int defTimeOut = Settings.System.getInt(m_context.getContentResolver(), 
            Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 3000);
    // set 15 sec
    Settings.System.putInt(m_context.getContentResolver(), 
            Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 15000);

    // wait 200 sec till get response from BroadcastReceiver on Screen Off
    mSync.doWait(wait*1000);


    // set previous settings
    Settings.System.putInt(m_context.getContentResolver(), 
            Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, defTimeOut);

    // switch back previous state
    Settings.System.putInt(
            m_context.getContentResolver(), 
            Settings.System.STAY_ON_WHILE_PLUGGED_IN,
            BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB);


    m_context.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);


}





public void broadCastListenerCallBack__ScreenOff_onResponse() {
    mSync.doNotify();
}

....
```

**AndroidSynchronize class**

```
public class AndroidSynchronize {

    public void doWait(long l){
        synchronized(this){
            try {
                this.wait(l);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }       

    public void doNotify() {
        synchronized(this) {
            this.notify();
        }
    }   

    public void doWait() {
        synchronized(this){
            try {
                this.wait();
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**[EDIT]**

You need to register permission:

```
android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
```

Comment: tried your method, but it's important to mention that it require **android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS**, which is otherwise not needed for 99% of apps.

Comment: What is the `main class`? Tried in my `MainActivity.java`, but `BroadCastListenerCallBackItf broadCastListenerCallBack = this;` failed.

Comment: @Deqing be sure that `MainActivity implements BroadCastListenerCallBackItf`

Comment: thanks this is the same idea I came up with.  during those 15 seconds I started a countdown timer so the user can set a WAKE lock if they want.  and then remove the wake lock only when the POWER_CONNECTED event.

Comment: Nice solution! I have one question:

Why in "mSync.doWait(wait*1000);" we have to wait a certain amount of time? I mean, why don't we wait until the broadcast receives the "screen off" signal and THEN release the wait so we can set the previous settings..etc?

Comment: @lettomobile just an example, you can use `wait()`

Answer (score 2):

Per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696891/programmatically-set-screen-to-off-in-android?lq=1), You can also turn the screen off like this:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 1000);
```

1000 is in milliseconds which means 1 second, you can replace it with any value as desired.

Needed permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: Tried this, screen still takes around 10 seconds to go off.

Comment: Although it does work you probably don't want to do this unless you also read the timeout and set the timeout back to it's original value afterwards; however if your app crashes for any reason at all you (or worse, the user) have a device in their hands that sleeps after one second (and can't change the setting anymore in that way to small amount of time) this setting also survives a reboot and you have a completely useless device (it was already difficult to reboot with this setting set...)

Comment: This is really dangerous. How to turn the screen back to ON?

Comment: Is it possible to handle screen touches when the screen is in off mode?

Answer (score -2):

try -
       wakeLock.acquire(1000); // specify the time , it dims out and eventually turns off.

Comment: I believe you are talking about Screen time out, and it's not related to wakelock.acquire(1000); // wakelock is released after 1 second, then phone's screen time out is doing it's job.