# Android Turn screen Off

Tags: android, screen

I can't turn off the screen using this code. I used `PowerManager` and `wl.release()` method, but it doesn't work. Can somebody show me an example?

```
  PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
   wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "DoNotDimScreen");
```

This is part of my function:

```
  stateString = "nextone";
  if(stateString=="nextone"){        
  wl.release();
   }
```

I also added permission in the manifest but no result.

Comment: Well, your comparison with stateString will never be true. To compare strings in java you should use `stateString.equals("nextone")` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer over here on stack overflow: [Turn off screen on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756768/turn-off-screen-on-android/6757206#6757206)

Copied from there:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes(); 
params.flags |= LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON; 
params.screenBrightness = 0; 
getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

I tried this out and it seems to work.

Comment: this solve the problem: getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

Comment: this code works fine to turn off screen,but how to turn it on back ?

Comment: Setting params.screenBrightness to a value between 0 and 1 gives you brightness between 0% and 100%.  Setting it to a negative value gives you auto brightness.  I forget where I 1st saw this, but I use it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use a permission, the program will crash with a `SecurityException` when it tries to lock, so that isn't the problem. The correct method is: (obtains WakeLock on start, gives it up when the application loses focus (onPause)

```
//declared globally so both functions can access this
public PowerManager.WakeLock wl;

///////////onCreate
//stop phone from sleeping
PowerManager powman = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wl = powman.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, "NameOfLock");
wl.acquire();

///////////onPause
wl.release();

//////////for completion's sake, onResume
if(!wl.isHeld()){
    wl.acquire();
}
```

However, your problem is actually in this check

> `if(stateString=="nextone")`

This should be `if(stateString.equals("nextone"))`

Answer (score 0):

please check this link before proceeding with wake lock. if it does not solve your problem then you can proceed with wake lock.

[Force Screen On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131948/force-screen-on/2134602#2134602)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try 
{
    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 1000*15);
} 
catch (NumberFormatException e) 
{
    Log.e("aa", "could not persist screen timeout setting", e);
}
```

[How to detect switching between user and device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631098/how-to-detect-switching-between-user-and-device)