# how to find out screen status on an android device?

Tags: android, screen, status, light

Is there any way to find out that the android device screen is on or not without broadcast receivers? I want to make minute interval updates on device via service that is invoked by alarm manager. I also want to preserve battery life. So the update service will run if the device screen is on.

i found a solution to my problem with this code:

```
PowerManager powermanager;
powermanager = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
if (powermanager.isScreenOn())
    {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider another approach to the problem:

Using Broadcast Receivers, set your repeating alarm when the screen is turned on. Then, when the screen is turned off, cancel your alarm.