# Turn off Screen/Keep screen when phone is ringing

Tags: android, screen, call

While the phone is ringing, how do I keep the screen off. Here is my code so far.

```
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:


            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Next time look deeply ;)

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756768/turn-off-screen-on-android
 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561320/android-how-to-turn-screen-on-and-off-programmatically

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I have already came across this article and could not really understand it or to use the code in that article to solve my problem. If you or someone else could make an example for me. I would be grateful.