# programmatically turn screen off in Android phone from another thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, lockscreen, wakelock

I'm trying to turn off the screen of an Android phone.

I read many other discussions, and tried two ways discribed here:
[Turn off screen on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756768/turn-off-screen-on-android/6757206#6757206)

In fact, what I really need to do is to launch the lock screen (the one that asks for the PIN). I wasn't sure how to do that and couldn't find documentation about it, so I tried to turn off the screen and hoped that it will display the lock screen when I turn the phone back on. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to test my theory.

First option:

```
PowerManager manager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = manager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Your Tag");    
wl.acquire();    
wl.release();
```

Second option:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();   
params.flags |= LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;    
params.screenBrightness = 0;    
getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

First option did nothing, and the second option caused my app to crash. In the stack call, I saw a suspicious log:
`Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.` I do call this code from another thread, running in the background (not the main thread).
Is it possible that this is causing the crash? How can I overcome this problem?
Is there another way to programmatically launch the lock screen, without having to turn off the screen?

Comment: post your error logs

Comment: I don't know how it's done in Android specifically, but most GUI frameworks provide some means for an arbitrary thread to post _tasks_ to a queue where they will be found and executed by the/a GUI event handler thread.

Answer (score 1):

In first option, add ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP as well. That would wake up the screen and show lock screen.

```
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = manager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "Your Tag");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it's still doesn't work (nothing happens...).

Comment: Okay, I read the post once again and I might have misunderstood earlier. I think you are trying to do is - lock the screen from your app itself. If that is true, this discussion will be helpful for you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352648/how-to-lock-unlock-screen-programmatically.