# Screen never off but saving battery

Tags: android, screen, battery

I use this code for have the screen always on

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

I'd like to know there is the option that device set the low light if the user is inactive (saving battery).

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803248/dim-screen-while-user-inactive

Comment: It doesn't help for my case. Thanks.